# dos batch file for move of files

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to move files in a directory (we have 1.7 million) to folders based upon a date?
WOuld like to move all files created between 1-1-2010 and 2-1-2010 to a specific folder

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Robocopy feature. It comes as default in Windows Vista and Windows 7 and you can download it in Windows XP in the microsoft website.

If your Windows is 64 bit it even move files that have a path longer than 256 characters, unlike the CTRL+C, CTRL+V on Windows Explorer (I can't understand why). To see the program help you can write the following in the DOS Prompt (example, usually you can't write to the root):

```
robocopy /? > c:\robocopyhelp.txt
```

Use the switches "/MINAGE" for setting the minimum age of the file to be copied/moved and "/MAXAGE" for setting the maximum age.

I've never moved files before and never tried to filter them by age, but I think the syntax should be (from drive F to G, for example, and only 2011 files):

```
robocopy F:\ G:\ /MOVE /MAXAGE:20110101 /MINAGE:20111231
```

Plus other parameters described on the "robocopy /?". Usually I add "/R:0 /W:0", for it not try to access systems files (can help if you run the batch file with administrator privileges) 1 million times with a wait time of 2 seconds for each system file it can't copy/move (2 million seconds or 23 days for just pagefile.sys and hiberfil.sys). And the "/A-:H" switch to un-hide the hidden files.

Keep in mind also the existence of NTFS Junctions (infinite loop in the C:\users directory) and encrypted directories and use the according switches.

Comment: Beat me by seconds. Probably want /MOV (move files only) instead of /MOVE (files and folders). /MINAGE and /MAXAGE are reversed (it is counter intuitive)

Comment: Corrected the /MINAGE and /MAXAGE values, thank you.
I do not know what the user problem is, so I'd kept the "/MOVE" approach. Some files are not self-explainable.

My use of robocopy is for huge directory copies and backups, so I usually copy everything, not time based.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be very nice, but you could use `forfiles` twice. Once to move all files with a date greater than 2010-01-01 to the folder and a second time to move all files with a date greater than 2010-??-?? (can't parse your date format reliably) back to the original folder.

Not pretty, definitely.